# Stochastic Differential Equations using Euler Method in Matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, stochastic

I am trying to solve a system of two stochastic differential equations using "sde_euler". Here is my code:

```
function y = stoch_Fx_model(t0,tf,F0,x0)


r=1;
sig=1;
lambda=1;
h=1;
S=1;

f= @(t,Y)[r.*Y(1).*(1-Y(1)) -h.*Y(1).*(1-Y(2))./(Y(1)+S);
     lambda.*Y(2).*(1-Y(2)).*(1+sig.*(2.*Y(2)-2.*Y(1)-1))];
g=@(t,Y)[0.5;0.6];
dt=0.001;
t=t0:dt:tf;
Y0=[F0;x0];

opts = sdeset('ConstGFUN','yes','NonNegative','yes');
y = sde_euler(f,g,t,Y0,opts);
y = min(y,1);

plot(t,y(:,1))

end
```

After specifying the values of t0,tf,x0,F0 I run the code and I am encountering the following error:

```
Error using sdearguments (line 22)
Input vector TSPAN must have length >= 2.  See SDE_EULER.

Error in sde_euler (line 130)
      [N,D,tspan,tdir,lt,y0,fout,gout,dgout,dg,h,ConstStep,dataType,NonNegative,...

Error in stoch_Fx_model (line 19)
y = sde_euler(f,g,t,Y0,opts);
```

I don't understand my mistake. my TSPAN is greater than 2 in length. Here is the source for the toolbox:

https://github.com/horchler/SDETools/blob/master/SDETools/sde_euler.m

Any help please?
thank you!

Comment: What are your values for `t0` and `tf`?  The hard-coded `dt` may be too large.

Comment: t0=0, tf=100. They represent years.. I tried t0=0, tf=10, smaller and larger dt.. but nothing worked.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.  Could post the script you used to call `stoch_Fx_model`?

Comment: stoch_Fx_model(0,100,0.5,0.01)
are you getting a plot?

Comment: Yes.  I'd restart/`clear all` and make sure you have Matlab pointing to the correct version.  If the problem persists, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Also, in your definition of `f`, you will need to remove the space before `-h`; otherwise, Matlab will interpret the space as a column separator due to the literal array context. ... I **really** wish I could turn that off and force `,`-usage.

Comment: oh wow! the space before "-h" made the difference! I got the plot!! Thank you :) **I wish that too**